# Reflected XSS - Automatic understanding of filters

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, xss, injection

I'm currently facing this possible reflected XSS vulnerability on a webapp:

URL = `http://www.test.com/login/?login=[PAYLOAD]`

When a user clicks on this link, it displays a login page that includes the following code:

```
<a href="http://www.test.com/login/[PAYLOAD]><img...></img></a>
```

I tried to close the `<a>` tag using `>` with different encodings, but this is filtered and displayed as `%3E`. I also tried to close the double quote and use some things like onclick etc. but this is filtered as well.

So I was wondering, is there any tool out there that can automatically test all characters in a given set with different encodings to see what is filtered ?

I could create my own script to do that, but it might save some time and well... reinventing the wheel..

**Update**:
So it appears that there is no tool that provide such capability. ie: test and report for every input what is filtered (and how it renders) or what is not. Burp ends up being the best solution to do that semi-manually, and a Burp extension can be done to fully automate this process.

Comment: Very nice and well presented a question. A well-deserved +1 from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably use [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) to do this.  [Burp Proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html) will let you intercept an HTTP request to a specific URL, `http://www.test.com/login/?login=[PAYLOAD]` for example.

Once you have intercepted this request you can specify which of the parameters you would like to target using [Burp Intruder](http://portswigger.net/burp/intruder.html)(in this case `login`).

Next you can specify a payload that you would like to apply to this parameter.  You can choose from a number of existing payloads or you can create your own.

When you begin the attack it will fire a request with every item in your payload set and give you a number of options for examining the result, such as grepping for the payload to see if it made it through intact.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Comment: I was wondering as well ? I'll try with Burp Intruder tomorrow, i'm unsure the grep part can be automated as I'd like. I want to see if I can still escape the <a> tag for this particular case, but basically what I would like also is a list, for each input, of what's filtered / what's not.

Comment: Right on, let me know how it turns out!  The grep functionality may work for your needs.  Basically you would grep the response to see if the un-encoded character is in there.  So if you submit `>` in the payload you would grep for `<a href="http://www.test.com/login/>`.  If it is encoded the response will contain `<a href="http://www.test.com/login/%3E` instead, so it will say there is no match.  Let me know if that is confusing.

Comment: So I did this with Burp Intruder for this particular test and it worked fine, but after looking everywhere it appears there's no software/plugin to do this automatically on every input you want. Thank you anyway I'll mark this as the right answer.

Comment: Hrrm, you should be able to specify your own input file. I use the pay version so maybe that is a paid feature?

Comment: I wasn't clear, there's no problem with Burp, I am able to specify my own input file. What I meant is there's no "point & click" software to do this with a neat report showing the "filtering level" for every input of a webpage/site (as that was my original question).